# Recursion error- unreachable

Tags: c#

So I am trying to create a simple recursion loop, but I am running into a problem.

After the first return line, it tells me that everything else under it is unreachable, However it needs the first return for recursion to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Program
{
    public static int i = 5;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        name(5);
    }

    public static int name(int i)
    { 
        if (i < 0)
        { }
        return i;
        if (i > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            i--;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to proofread both your post and your code. Your first `return` statement in `name()` will *always* be hit. The `if` statement above it has an empty block attached to it (the `{ }`) - so when the `if` is hit, it does nothing. Whether or not the `if` is hit, the next instruction is a return. Also note that to have recursion you must call `name()` again from within `name()`. I'm *guessing* you want it immediately following the `i--;` line.

Comment: Before you tackle recursion (which is rarely necessary) I think you need to get a bit more comfortable with the language and the debugger.

Comment: I see no recursion here. Beside the currently given answers, what do you want to achieve with recursion?

Comment: ah, i see,thanks, i fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your method code is unreachable because you are calling `return` before it and the method always returns the value at `return i` so the code after it will never be executed.

```
if (i < 0)
{ }
return i;//problem here//code after this line gets never executed
```

And recursive methods are methods that call itself inside the method body, so if you are making a recursive method you probably want something like this:

```
public static int name(int i)
{
     if (i == 0)
        return i;
     Console.WriteLine(i);
     return name(--i);
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OAB3Ex)**

Comment: i see, so my problem was that i didn't run the program back into itself.

Comment: If you are making a recursive method the method has to call itself inside the method body, therefore your method wasn't recursive. Another problem lies in the unreachable code because you are calling return before it and the method always returns the value at this line of code so the code after it will never be executed.

Comment: @LionBlaze Check out the demo I posted!

Answer (score 0):

Quiet simple. You have the first return outside the {} so it occurs to anything that goes through. You want to put it inside the if statement

```
public static int i = 5;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    name(5);
}
public static int name(int i)
{
    if (i < 0)
    {
        return i;
    }

    if (i > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        i--;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: There is no recursion in this answer or the question.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?
>   You are returning from a function before the rest of the code block .I feel you should first go through How return works.Anyway just do the following

```
 if (i < 0)
 {
      return i;
 }
```